# Java Selenium Click a certain button on a certain day

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm having an issue with clicking a button on a certain day. The website I'm scripting for has couple of options. Week, Month and Year. When you press Week you get the option to select the day of the week. Monday, Tuesday and so on. When you press Month, you get the same thing for months.

My issue is how do I automate it so when I need to select the day of the week it checks the date and selects the correct date.

I have no issue with checking the date or clicking a button I just don't know how to combine the two.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Chow us some of your code so it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to get a match between current weekday and one the seven webelements. An example of selecting weekday on the web https://www.phpro.org/examples/Days-Of-Week-Dropdown.html:

```
public void selectCorrectWeekday() throws InterruptedException {

    String weekDayCapitalized = weekDay().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + weekDay().substring(1);
    driver.get("https://www.phpro.org/examples/Days-Of-Week-Dropdown.html");
    new Select(waitSec(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("day")))).selectByVisibleText(weekDayCapitalized);
    Thread.sleep(5000);

}

public WebDriverWait waitSec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);}    
public String weekDay() {return today().getDayOfWeek().name().toString().toLowerCase();}
public LocalDate today() {LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();return today;}
```

However your approach will be different due to html source code.

Comment: One more thing. Remove `Thread.sleep(5000);` which is located in `selectCorrectWeekday()`.  Replace it with more relevant code, which for example verify some state.